# ActionbarSherlock and ViewpagerIndicator: how to add different actionbar menu to different Page in ViewPagerIndicator using fragment

Tags: android-viewpager, actionbarsherlock, viewpagerindicator

My app use an `Actionbarsherlock` with a `ViewpagerIndicator`. Each page using 1 fragment. I want each page will have different actionbar menu, so how can I archive this?

I have tried using `onCreateOptionsMenu` on each `SherlockFragment` but the actionbar menu not show, I also tried finding some methods to add menu programmatically but no way.

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu, com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater inflater)
{       
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);    
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

Thanks you!

****EDIT: Add more details ****

If i use onCreateOptionsMenu in the Activity, the menu (action item) show normally.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
```

This is how I set  up the ActionBar the the ViewPager

```
final ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionbar .setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionbar .setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionbar .setTitle("olala");

    mFragmentAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());     
    mPager.setAdapter(mFragmentAdapter);

    mIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);
    mIndicator.setOnPageChangeListener(new MyPageChangeListener());
    mPager.setCurrentItem(3);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We need to add this on Fragment (onCreate or onCreateView) in order to report that this fragment would like to participate in populating the options menu by receiving a call to onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu, MenuInflater) and related methods.

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

ref: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

Comment: *facepalm* true! Sorry, I totally missed that :/

Answer (score 1):

I have the same without the call to `super`.

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.chat_thread_list_fragment_menu, menu);
}
```

Update:

I have set this in my onCreate of the Activity...

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.profile_activity);
    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.profile_activity_pager);

    final Intent intent = getIntent();

    // I guess some setup should be done...
    final ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    bar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    if (intent.hasExtra(EXTRA_USER_NAME)) {
        bar.setTitle(intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_USER_NAME));
    } else {
        bar.setTitle(R.string.title_profile);
    }

    final PagerAdapter tabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this);
    viewPager.setAdapter(tabsAdapter);

    final TitlePageIndicator titleIndicator = (TitlePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.profile_activity_tabs);
    titleIndicator.setViewPager(viewPager);

    if (intent.hasExtra(EXTRA_TAB_ID)) {
        final int tabId = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_TAB_ID, -1);
        if (tabId > -1 && tabId < tabsAdapter.getCount()) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tabId);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just use actionbar style for Actvity on Manifest. Am I missing something?

Comment: I set some stuff for the actionbar, maybe you should try it, too

Comment: Thank u for your kind support, but the menu (action item) still not show. I just added more detail on the question.

Comment: could you try to set the global theme to `Theme.Sherlock` and don't specify something for the activity you use.

Comment: I'm sorry but nothing changed :(